# Any idea when this site will come out of Beta

Tags: discussion, top-7

We seem to be doing good on all the scores for the site. Any idea when the site will come out of beta and become a full site. There are some other site as well on area51 ahead of this site ...
Whom should we ask as to when this site will come out of beta?? Joel/Jeff are you guys reading here :)

Comment: Update: **We're next in line for graduation!**  See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11562316#11562316

Answer (score 7):

The order of graduating sites is re-evaluated after each launch so this "schedule" is tentative:

[Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is going out this week, followed by [RPG](http://rpg.stackexchange.com). If I *had* to decide today (which I can't), it looks like the site after would be either [**Money**](http://money.stackexchange.com) or [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

So my best estimate right now would be about [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514)… kidding; **2 to 3-ish weeks.**

Comment: Great!  But hey -- did those RPG guys offer a bribe or something?  :-)

Comment: @Chris W. Rea: Either the numbers changed or I miscalculated. By the numbers, Money.SE is now 2nd. That's why I *shouldn't* pre-calculate these schedules. I'll have to see where @Jin is on the next design.

Comment: My comment was meant tongue-in-cheek :-) Jin probably doesn't need an unnecessary context switch, and those RPG guys... I wouldn't want them to cast a bad spell on us if we bumped them :-D  Anyway, I suspect your calculation was fine. Our visit numbers have improved rapidly in a short time.  I think we're popular in Google again, for some keywords.

Comment: Strategically, though, it would be nice to have the site design in place before tax-time .. so as long as that "6-8 weeks" is **firm**, we should be OK.  ;-)

Comment: @Chris No bribes, but we're more fun to design.  I think either one is a good choice.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Any update on an ETA for Money's graduation?  Tax time approacheth.

Comment: @Chris W. Rea: I haven't heard mention. I'll see if there is a change in the status. The consensus was that there's very little incremental benefit that a graduated site has over a beta... so, the hold up is that Money-SE's consistency and traffic hasn't yet *clearly* shown that it has reached that "Eureka" tipping point that all but *guarantees* future growth. Not that we're in any way thinking the site is going to do poorly; just that it's still in that let-it-bake-a-bit-longer neutral zone. I will make inquiries.

Comment: *<cough>* *<ahem>*  Each of *Programmers*, *RPG*, and *Unix* have been live for quite some time now, and we're approaching **"1000 days of beta."**  Please say our traffic pattern now warrants serious consideration of graduation? ;-)

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea That does look promising — and the growth wasn't even centered around tax season — nice job! Regular community evaluations are schedule every few months. I don't know where we are in that cycle, but we will definitely do a full graduation review once the results are completed.